# DRF APIClient Delete data arrives in request.data, not request.query_params

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I use DRF's APIClient to write automated tests. And while is was writing the first delete test, I found it very strange that the data passed through arrived in request.data, while if I use Axios or Postman, it always arrives in request.query_params.
Any explanation as to why this is, and preferably a method to use APIClient.Delete while the data arrives in query_params would be great!

My test:

```py
import pytest
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    client = APIClient()
    client.force_authenticate()
    yield client


class TestDelete:

    def test_delete(client):
        response = client.delete('/comment', data={'team': 0, 'id': 54})
```

And my views

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView



class Comments(APIView):

    def delete(self, request):
        print(request.query_params, request.data)


>>> <QueryDict: {}> <QueryDict: {'team': ['0'], 'id': ['54']}>
```

Looked into DRF's APIClient. Feeding towards params doesn't seem to help. The delete method doesn't seem to have direct arguments that could help as well. So I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: You receive request.data in a POST request while request.query_params in a GET request.

Comment: You may want to use `reverse` instead and format the url with that. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/55202406/13239055

Comment: response = client.delete('/comment', kwargs={'team': 0, 'id': 54})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though some good options have been proposed, they didn't work with DRF's APIView. I ended up using `urllib` and encode it manually:

```py
import pytest
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


@pytest.fixture()
def client():
    client = APIClient()
    client.force_authenticate()
    yield client


class TestDelete:

    def test_delete(client):
        response = client.delete(f'/comment{urlencode(data)}')
```